# Assigning different labels in coefplot

Tags: stata

I have executed the code snippet below:

```
foreach yr in 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 {
    eststo: ivregress 2sls y (var=z) c [aw=w] if yr==`yr'
    estimate store r`yr'
}

coefplot r2000 r2001 r2002 r2003 r2004 r2005 r2006 , vertical keep(var)
```

This produced the following graph:

[image]

However, I want to change the label in `x-axis` to `2000`, `2001`, ..., `2006`.

As you can see, I am using the *community-contributed* command`coefplot` but these coefficients are from separate regressions, and `2000` or `2001` are not variable names.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stata's `auto` toy dataset:

```
sysuse auto, clear
recode foreign (0 = 1) (1 = 2)

forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
    eststo: regress mpg price if foreign == `i'
    estimate store r`i'
}
```

The following does the trick:

```
coefplot (r1 \ r2), vertical keep(price) aseq swapnames
```

[image]

Or with custom labels:

```
coefplot (r1, aseq(Foreign 1) \ r2, aseq(Foreign 2)), vertical keep(price) swapnames
```

[image]